# Symbols "degrees" and "degrees centigrade": proper spacing

Tags: typography, kerning, white-space

For mathematical and physical units, usually there is a thin space between the number and the unit, in the LaTeX syntax for example `$1008\,\mathrm{kPa}$`.

However, I feel that angular degrees (e.g. `$90°$`), temperature degrees (e.g. `$-2°\mathrm{C}$`), and NESW degrees (e.g. `$90°\mathrm{S}$`) should be typeset without spaces.

What is the correct spacing of these?

Comment: Doesn't `situnitx` handle this automagically?

Comment: @MartinSchröder It does I suppose, the question is whether it does it correctly, especially the NESW case...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're half right!

> In the case of degrees of arc, the degree symbol follows the number without any intervening space.
>
> In the case of degrees of temperature, two scientific and engineering standards bodies (BIPM and the U.S. Government Printing Office) prescribe printing temperatures with a space between the number and the degree symbol, as in 10 °C.[2][3]

Source: [*Degree symbol* on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_symbol)

Comment: Note that the continuation on Wikipedia says "However, in many works with professional typesetting, including scientific works published by the University of Chicago Press or Oxford University Press, the degree symbol is printed with no spaces between the number, the symbol, and the Latin letters "C" or "F" representing Celsius or Fahrenheit, respectively (e.g., 10°C)."